# Reading out all operators in a header's menu

Tags: python, interface, operator

How is it possible to read out the menus of a header and the operators in the menus with Python?

Background:
I have an external hardware with some configurable keys, and I want to trigger the operators in Blender's menus with the keys. In the hardware's GUI is a dialog to assign functions to the keys. In this dialog is a list of available functions, and I try to fill this list with all of Blender's menu items. If possible the list should show up in the same hierarchical structure (menus and submenus) as in Blender and reflecting the actual state Blender is in.

Answer (score 1):

There's no straight-forward way to retrieve the contents of menus or other layout types.

If possible, create shortcuts in the *User Preferences*, but that might not be possible with external hardware keys. Or if that's sufficient for you, *Right-click > Edit Source* to see the layout code (mostly python-scripted).

It might be feasible to extract layout information somehow by hacking deep into the Blender internals with Python, see this to get an idea:

http://wiki.blender.org/index.php?title=Dev:2.5/Py/Scripts/Cookbook/Code_snippets/Interface&oldid=226944#Overriding_Interface_Elements

Comment: The atttibutes "label", "menu" and "operator" of bpy.types.Header.layout seem to contain the information I am looking for. What I'd need is a list of all header objects currently defined. I hoped to get all header objects of a screen by looping over all areas and regions and searching for regions of type "Header". But it seems not to be possible to get the header object linked to a region. I will postpone the problem and perhaps come back later to it. Nevertheless, thank you for the answer.

Comment: If all you wanna know is **what** is there and not **where**, you can do `bpy.types.Header.__subclasses__()` to get all subclasses of Header, which are effectively all area headers regardless whether they are currently shown or not.

Comment: In my (limited) understanding of Python this gives me a list of all defined subclasses but not the concrete header objects I'd need to iterate over their contents. In any case, when assigning `h=bpy.types.Header.__subclasses__()[0]` e. g., I expected h to have access to h.bl_idname or h.layout; but it seems to have access only to the attributes of Header's base class bpy.types.bpy_struct and not to the attributes of bpy.types.Header.

Comment: You can't access the "header objects". Layouts are defined in Python and drawn by C code. The only way I can think of is to replace the UILayout type to hook into the layout drawing system. It might only give you the currently drawn elements however.

Comment: Perhaps I try to parse the files space*.py in the startup script folder; there are only few labels for the operators though - may be a look into the localisation files could help for this. But this is work for next year ...